# How to convert input name to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue related to converting html inputs names to a javascript object.
For example I have an input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[1]">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[2]">
```

and I have javascript code:

```
var data = {};
$('input').each(function(){
    // need to do something like 
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('checked');
})
```

I expect to get data object like this;

```
data = {
    product: {
        1: 'checked',
        2: 'checked'
    }
}
```

Is this possible without using regular expressions?

Comment: tough to tell what you want from the example.  what is the name of the input in that example?

Comment: He wants a result that is two levels deep, as the value of `name` implies.

Comment: Frits van Campen is right. I need two levels deep array/object

Comment: @FritsvanCampen the question was edited after that comment :)

Comment: can you use different input names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing your variables with literal values, you get this:

```
data["product[1]"] = true;
```

The square brackets have no meaning as they are inside a string, so you won't get any result.

There are ways around this. You *could* use eval: `eval("data."+this.name+" = "+(this.checked?"true":"false"));`

However since `eval` is best avoided, try this:

```
var m = this.name.match(/(.*)\[(\d+)\]/);
data[m[0]][m[1]] = this.checked;
```

Comment: eval("data."+this.name+" = "+(this.checked?"true":"false")); - GREAT!!! Thanks!
I have tried eval(this.name) but got "undefined variable product...". Thank you too much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes in general it is possible. You can do the following:

```
var noregexp = $(this).attr('name').split("[");
if (noregexp.length==2) {
    //should be
    var the_name = noregexp[0];
    var the_index = noregexp[1].substr(0,noregexp[1].length-1); //this will get the index with removed ]
}
```

I made this up from my mind. It's not a beautiful solution but one without regexp as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a data structure the way you need using:

```
var data = {product: []};
$('input').each(function(){
    data.product[$(this).attr('name').match(/product\[([\d]*)\]/)[1]] = $(this).prop('checked');
})
console.log(data);
```

Check thid **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AFMbX/)**