# Convert complex input names to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some complex input names like: `this[is][][a][complex][name]` and I need convert it to an array/object. Like:

```
{ "this": { "is": [ { "a": { "complex": { "name": true } } } ] } }
```

How can I do that with pure javascript or jquery?

**REASON**

I need send it with jQuery.ajax() method like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    "data": {
        "complex": complex_names,
        "time": Date.now()
     }, ...
});
```

If I just serialize data like `this[is][][a][complex][name]=true`, it broke the HTTP request, and sends it like `data[this[is][][a][complex][name]]` instead of `data[this][is][][a][complex][name]`.

**EXAMPLE**

I did this example to help you. Well, suppose that I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="test1" value="ok" />
<input type="text" name="test2" value="ok" />
<input type="text" name="test3[1]" value="ok" />
<input type="text" name="test4[1][2]" value="ok" />
<input type="text" name="test5[]" value="ok" />
```

If I send it directly via POST, it'll generate a request like:

```
test1: ok
test2: ok
test3[1]: ok
test4[1][2]: ok
test5[]: ok
```

But I need send it via jQuery.ajax() method, inside of a array in `data` option (like `complex_data` with some other data). The request will be similar to:

```
call_time: 1612
call_title: test
complex_data[test1]: ok
complex_data[test2]: ok
complex_data[test3][1]: ok
complex_data[test4][1][2]: ok
complex_data[test5][]: ok
```

Note that my form input will be set inside `complex_data` object. But if I just convert my data as an array, like:

```
{
  "test1": "ok",
  "test2": "ok",
  "test3[1]": "ok",
  "test4[1][2]": "ok",
  "test5[]": "ok",
}
```

And send it to `complex_data`, it'll request it, instead:

ta). The request will be similar to:

```
call_time: 1612
call_title: test
complex_data[test1]: ok
complex_data[test2]: ok
complex_data[test3][1]]: ok
complex_data[test4][1][2]]: ok
complex_data[test5][]]: ok
```

Simplified case like `test1` nad `test2` will work fine, but complex cases like `test3[1]` will not be understand and will broke.

**WORKAROUND**

Currently I'm using a workaround solution that create an array like: `this][is][][a][complex` and it is included by HTTP request into `data[...]` what turn to `data[`**`this][is][][a][complex][name`**`]`.

**RESEARCH**

It's similar to [How to convert input name to JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162663/how-to-convert-input-name-to-javscript-array) question, but it is a bit more complex because the deepness is 0 to infinite (generally to level 3). So, I can't make anything unless I use eval (!).

Comment: What is your logic for determining whether a `[]` or a `{}` should be used? You seem to be mixing them in your example, but I don't understand why which is used. **EDIT:** Nevermind, I think I'm realizing it now...

Comment: Can't you just use serialize method?

Comment: Serialize method generate a good result if I send it directly to AJAX `data` option. But if I need to send it to an array and send it to AJAX, it broken (just like **reason** topic). I'll try to improve the example.

Comment: So `this[is][][a][complex][name]=true` is a string?

Comment: @amnotiam Yeah I think so. And it should be converted into an object/array structure

Comment: @Ian: I'm not so sure about that. There's too much mixing of the actual problem and the attempted solution in this question. It's hard to tell what OP ultimately wants to send in the request.

Comment: @amnotiam Yeah, I continue re-reading the question and just keep getting more confused...I probably shouldn't have answered you like I knew what what was going on :)

Comment: I did a more detailed example. Please, read if you can.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but maybe you can articulate what you want to pass to a function and what you want it to produce as a unit test?  Here is a basic qunit page: http://jsfiddle.net/PFkDF/ to help debug various approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem, here is what I came up with:

```
function convert(s) {
    var names = s.replace(/^\w+/, "$&]").replace(/]$/, "").split("][");
    var result = {};
    var obj = result;
    var last;
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var name = names[i];
        if (typeof last !== "undefined") {
            obj[last] = name === "" ? [] : {};
            obj = obj[last];
        }
        last = name === "" ? 0 : name;
    }
    obj[last] = true;
    return result;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QdRvz/

Comment: It don't apply to my case. It only will consider 1 complex name and set it to true, I need to apply that to a serialized string from a form. But thanks. :)

Comment: Hmm, your question is kind of confusing then, it seems like this is exactly what you ask for in the first sentence.